# "sequence_id" in Box.com Create Folder API call

Tags: box-api

In Box.com API document it is written that, if you will create a folder then you will get some response.

So I have gone through the response, and wondering what is "sequence_id" means in this block of of code.

```
"parent": {
        "type": "folder",
        "id": "0",
        "sequence_id": null,
        "etag": null,
        "name": "All Files"
    },
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The folder with id=0 is the users "root" folder.   As such it isn't a real folder with an etag or a sequence_id.  Every other folder at every other level will have a non-zero id, and will have a sequence_id and a non-null etag.

Comment: While creating a folder under parent folder, the 'sequence_id' which I mentioned above keeps changing. otherwise if you are having only parent folder then this sequence_id will be 'null', like it is mentioned above.

Comment: @seanroseless : do you have any idea? how to create a folder with in a parent folder?

For creating a sub folder with in a parent folder I am passing parent folder id while creating sub folder.